# Technical Debt decreased after migration

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, technical-debt

We just migrate from SQ-4.2 to the last LTS 4.5.6.
And we noticed a strange behaviour:

- On 4.5.6 de technical debt cost get drastically reduced, while the number of issues get increased (please see attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwD76.jpg)

We didn't find any answer to this behaviour (change in formulas? in each violation remediation cost?)

Before migration (on 4.2): sonar-java-plugin-2.5.jar
After (on 4.5.6): sonar-java-plugin-3.9.jar

Thank you in advance for any clarification,
Issam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.0 version included a wide-ranging reassessment of technical debt values. We had realized that many were much higher than they ought to be, so this was addressed in [SONARJAVA-873](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-873).

For instance S1192 went from 10 minutes to 2 minutes.

That's why you can have more issues but less time after this upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Ann for your answer

Comment: G. Ann, can you confirm that the same true-up occurred for the C# rules? I just upgraded to 5.10.0.1344 after about a year hiatus. Seeing a huge drop in number of issues and time.

Comment: @virsum it occurred across the board for all languages.